# Stop Background audio service flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

When I play some music using `just_audio` & ```just_audio_background``, it keeps playing even when I kill my app from the background.

I want to stop the music and remove the notification tray when the user kills the app.

I tried AppLifeCycle methods and disposed audio player on detached but it is just leaking and the flutter UI is destroyed.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "kill my app"? Do mean on Android where you swipe the app up in the task manager? If so, that doesn't actually kill the app, it only kills the activity. I just want to be clear on what you mean before writing an answer.

Comment: Yes I am talking about when swipe the app up in the task manager.

Comment: But do you mean on Android specifically? If so, then you need to listen to that event with `onTaskRemoved`.

Comment: Yes on android. How I can listen onTaskRemoved ? any code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android, removing the task does not mean killing the app. Any background services will still continue to run. What you can do is listen to the event of a task being removed, and then respond to that event by invoking the `stop()` method on your player to cause the audio to stop.

However, you mentioned that you are not using the audio_service package directly, you are instead using the convenience package just_audio_background which provides only a subset of the features of audio_service.

So if you want access to more features such as this one, you need to use the more powerful audio_service. In your subclass of `BaseAudioHandler`, simply provide the following override:

```dart
  @override
  Future<void> onTaskRemoved() => _player.stop();
```